# Can MediaDevices.getDisplayMedia be used to take a visitors screenshot?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

It doesn't seem to be very clear for me, it is suppose to ask for permission to the user but I keep getting the error "Error: NotAllowedError: Permission denied by system".

Is it a feature that is on testing

Example online
https://jsfiddle.net/rdz7q135/

I took the example from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

Quick short demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/9dm4ws61/

```
async function startCapture(displayMediaOptions) {
let captureStream = null;

  try {
    captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
    console.log(captureStream);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("Error: " + err);
  }
  return captureStream;
}


$('#demo').click(function(){
    startCapture({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on MacOS? The first-time user experience of getUserMedia is not ideal, [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/C1T2wGEaakQ/m/jQOUNA_QBAAJ) has the details.

Comment: Yeaep using Catalina. But... I read no proper solution on there. It seems users can't really make use of this feature unless they touch their system?